# Finding second virial coefficient from a potential

Tags: statistical-mechanics, approximations, virial-theorem

Given the potential $\phi = \alpha/r^n$, I want to find the second virial coefficient of my system. My integration limits are from some cut-off length $D$ because the particles don't experience a self-force.
This was my procedure:
$$B_2(T) = -2\pi \int_{0}^{\infty} (e^{-\beta \alpha /r^n} -1) r^2 dr \\
    = -2\pi \int_{0}^{\infty} r^2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{(\beta \alpha)^k}{r^{kn} k!} dr \\
    = -2\pi \int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{(\beta \alpha)^kr^{-kn+2}}{ k!} dr \\
    = -2\pi \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{D}^{\infty}  (-1)^k \frac{(\beta \alpha)^kr^{-kn+2}}{ k!} dr \\
    = -2\pi \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac{(\beta \alpha)^k}{ k!} \int_{D}^{\infty} r^{-kn+2}dr \\ 
    = -2\pi \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac{(\beta \alpha)^k}{ k!} \cdot \frac{r^{-kn+3}}{-kn+3} \bigg|_{D} ^{\infty} \\
    = 2\pi \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac{(\beta \alpha)^k}{ k!} \cdot \frac{D^{-kn+3}}{-kn+3}$$

My question is, is there a well-defined function with a Maclaurin series defined as the last line?

Comment: Probably Math SE would be more suitable for this question

Comment: I think that your potential is $\phi=\alpha/r^n$ and not $e^{-\alpha/r^n}$.

Comment: The substitution $u=\beta \alpha r^{-n}$ might leave you with a couple of integrals that reduce to gamma functions, although the value of $n$ seems a potential issue.

Comment: @StephenG is my method incorrect?

Comment: The sum you have is convergent. So, yes, there is a well-defined function.  It's probably not any kind of standard function though.